# Link from email to navigate to given section in an angular app (MVC areas)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, areas

I have an ASP .NET MVC areas / AngularJS app.

I have the need to generate a link that will be sent out in an email. I would like users that read the email to be able to click the link and then be taken to the relevant section in the AngularJS application.

What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.